# Quick way to convert widestring LE -> BE

Tags: freepascal

I use Lazarus 1.2.6, I want to convert long widestrings: from LE-> BE or back. My code (i print as recall)

```
for i:= 1 to Length(s) do
  s[i]:= Widechar(SwapEndian(Ord(s[i])))
```

Any quicker method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no streaming endianness swap.